# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties

Tags: java, apache-commons

Trying to execute a java class main and i get the above error though I have in my lib folder the following libs :

1. commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
2. **commons-collections4-4.0.jar**
3. commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
4. commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
5. commons-io-1.3.2.jar
6. commons-lang.jar
7. commons-lang-2.6.jar

   I searched the google & I find references only for commons-collections4-4.0.jar but inside there is no class/folder such an ExtendedProperties. Any help ?

Comment: Could you try going back to commons collections version 3 (current version is 3.2.1)?  V4 is radically different from its predecessors.

Comment: In version 4 there isn't a ExtendedProperties class http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html

Comment: This is the exact solution. Problem solved!

Comment: Hi @StathisAndronikos : Howz your problem solved ?

Comment: Going back to previous version 3